# Pictures with no background or transparent in ArcGIS layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, layouts, transparency-opacity

I would like to add a .jpg, .png or .tiff with a no background. In other words, I want the logo to appear as it was created, without a border or background, to my Layout view.

Also is it possible to have a transparent logo.

Comment: Can't you use something like Gimp to drop out the background?

Comment: I believe he already has a transparent image but he is running into the problem where it will appear with a background when you go from Insert -> Picture from the ArcDesktop menu.

Answer (score 6):

Another nice work around I regularly use to insert my company's logo with a transparent background is to add an additional dataframe in layout view. Then bring the transparent background tif or png in as a layer, zoom to layer, go to the symbology tab in layer properties change Stretch to none and Display background value (R,G,B, / 0,0,0) as hollow. Ensure your dataframe background is also set to hollow and has no frame. You should have your image or logo with all of it's transparent background glory, in a usable form in layout view. (Change frame and use the zoom tools to get the image or logo to the size you'd like in your layout) This all sounds a bit cumbersome but once you have done it regularly it is a fairly quick work around to perform.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue, here is the work around

Open the image using Microsoft Word or PowerPoint, then right click on image and cut/copy and then paste the image into the ArcMap document in layout view.

source:
http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/25368

Comment: That seems to work,  but with a big reduction in resolution... is there a trick within the trick to maintain the same resolution?

Comment: Maybe try cutting and pasting it out of a graphics editing program